# Astro.js + MDX: Unexpected `ExpressionStatement` in code: only import/exports are supported

Tags: reactjs, astrojs, mdxjs

I'm trying to write a new blog post with MDX within my Astro.js blog, but it keeps throwing `Unexpected ExpressionStatement in code: only import/exports are supported` any time I include a React-based JSX component. Nothing online speaks of this problem.

Here's a larger trace:

```
 error   Unexpected `ExpressionStatement` in code: only import/exports are supported
  File:
    /home/username/projects/astro-blog/src/content/blog/test.mdx:2:1
  Code:
    1 | ---
    > 2 | title: "Test"
        | ^
```

`test.mdx`

```
---
title: "Test"
pubDate: "2023-11-30 00:41:27 -0500"
description: "Testing!"
---
import MapChart from "@components/MapChart.tsx";
<MapChart />
```

It's weird because it makes totally no sense, the error is completely irrelevant to what causes it.

`MapChart.tsx` (placeholder)

```
export default function MapChart() {
  return <div>Test Component</div>
}
```

If the import is removed, the error goes away and is replaced by an undefined component error. But if the component is removed, it doesn't complain. What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a newline of space between the import and the space lines. It's very dumb, and I only found it after searching the Astro discord.

Simply go from

```
---
title: "Test"
pubDate: "2023-11-30 00:41:27 -0500"
description: "Testing!"
---
import MapChart from "@components/MapChart.tsx";
<MapChart />
```

to

```
---
title: "Test"
pubDate: "2023-11-30 00:41:27 -0500"
description: "Testing!"
---
import MapChart from "@components/MapChart.tsx";

<MapChart />
```

And the problem will be resolved.

Comment: Live Saver. thanks!